# Ubuntu 16.10 doesn't work in virtual machine (VMware)

Tags: dell, vmware, virtualization, 16.10, vmware-workstation

Ubuntu 16.10 doesn't work in Virtual Machine. It gets installed though, but when powered on, it gives an error "Guest OS has disabled the CPU, Please power down or restart"
Even though I upgrade a VM of ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 same happens. Please Help!

All previous versions of ubuntu work fine on my VMware.

Comment: I 'made it work' by reducing the no. of cpus from 2 down to 1.... regards ... Ruud

Comment: See [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/402993#comment-16) for more details about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this bug was fixed by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/+source/linux/+bug/1630774/